# Remove matching values by comparing two database tables Codeigniter/Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter, mysqli

In my codeigniter model I have this function :

```
public function getUserNo()
{
    $query = $this->db->query("select userno from Users where active=1");
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

This code outputs the `userno` from the `Users` table.

I have another table called `Userslist` which also contains the `userno` field.

I want a query such that it first gets all the `userno` from the `Userlist` table and then check if they exist in the `Users` table and if they exist then return all the `userno` from the `Users` table except for those which are there in the `Userslist` table.
How do I write this query?

Comment: `select userno from Users where active= 1 AND userno NOT IN (SELECT userno FROM Userlist)`

Comment: Hey it works. can you post it as an answer so that I can accept and upvote it ?

Comment: Answer posted below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a sub query using the SQL NOT IN[enter link description here](http://beginner-sql-tutorial.com/sql-not-in.htm)

```
select userno from Users where active= 1 AND userno NOT IN (SELECT userno FROM Userlist)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select u.userno FROM Userlist as ui 
LEFT JOIN ON users as u 
u.userno=ui.userno WHERE u.active = 'active' GROUP BY u.userno
```